# Javascript value cuts off after '&' character

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I'm relatively new with Javascript and Ajax, and using them to submit data to the database for live updating, but I'm noticing that when there is a '&' character entered into my input/textareas, when I gets the value, it cuts the string off after the '&'.

I've tested the value by using the alert function after the lines of code below, and the full string is there, but not exactly sure how to fix this.

I tried to replace the '&' character with `&amp;` but can't get it to work. Here is what I used to get the values and the replace I tried to use. *Note: I'm using the nicEditor and have to use the first line of the code to get the text from the proper field that stores the text inside the editor.*

```
var boxval = $('#statusContentForum').find('.nicEdit-main').text();
var dataString = 'statusContent='+ boxval;
var dataString = dataString.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
var dataString = dataString.replace(/\|&;\$%@"<>\(\)\+,/g, "");
```

and used these characters to test it.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 1234567890-=`~!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]|\"':;,<.>?/
```

but it only results in this

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 1234567890-=`~!@#$%^
```

Have any of you encountered this before? I'd appreciate any help, and if you need more code let me know. I can provide it.

*********UPDAT FULL CODE *********

Here is the full code.

The JS/AJAX:

```
$(function() {
            //Update Message...
            $(".update_button").click(function() {
                //var boxval = $("#statusContent").val();
                var boxval = $('#statusContentForum').find('.nicEdit-main').text();
                var dataString = 'statusContent='+ boxval;

                //var dataString = dataString.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
                //var dataString = dataString.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
                var dataString = dataString.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
                var dataString = dataString.replace(/\|&;\$%@"<>\(\)\+,/g, "");

                if(boxval=='') {
                    alert("Please Enter Some Text");
                } else {
                    $("#flash").show();
                    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> <span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');
                    //  alert(dataString);
                    //  throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax/statusPost.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            $("ol#update").prepend(html);
                            $("ol#update li").slideDown("slow");
                            var clearVal = nicEditors.findEditor("statusContent");
                            clearVal.setContent("");
                            $("#flash").hide();
                        }
                    });
                } return false;
            });
});
```

The HTML if you need it.

```
<form name="newstatus" id="statusContentForum" action="profile.php" method="post" class="commentForm">
    <textarea name="statusContent" id="statusContent" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" class="update_button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is likely that you are trying to format the string for HTML instead of for whatever format you are using to send it over HTTP… but you've not provided the code where you try to send it over HTTP.

Comment: I'll provide the whole code here for you in another answer. I didn't think of that.. lol

Comment: Don't *answer* a question to provide more details about the problem. *Edit* the question instead.

Comment: To add more information to your question, or to edit it in any way at all, just click the [edit] link below the tags to your question. You don't need to post 'another answer' (or question). If you *do* post an answer to provide clarification it will be flagged as "not an answer," and/or down-voted. Posting another question (without first closing this one) will result in one of the questions being closed as a duplicate. Both of which carry (admittedly minor) penalties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're familiar with other programming languages, and perhaps even key words or sensitive characters. Always remember to look into that as a first solution to your issue. In this case, that's what was going on. If you encode the string for that variable you're setting it should work just fine.

Try console logging it.

```
console.log(encodeURIComponent('My Var: ' + dataString));
```

See here for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 2):

You are manually constructing [an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/iana.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded), but aren't encoding `&` correctly. To represent a `&` as data in that format you need to replace it with `%26`.

The `encodeURIComponent` function will do this for you.

However, you are using jQuery so you shouldn't do it manually at all. Pass `data` an object instead of a string.

```
data: {
    statusContent: boxval
},
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm trying to learn and understand everything, but at the same time I don't want to pester you with questions, but how do I apply the data: { part of your suggestion? Do I just put it  up where the var dataString is?

Comment: @logicK — you just put it where `data: dataString` is and get rid of everything relating to `dataString`.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. I can't get it to work right, and tried googling "javascript pass data an object", could you give me an example somehow?

Comment: You just replace the line in my comment with the three lines in my answer.

Comment: Sadly I couldn't get it to work.. :/ I did get the encodeURIComponent to work though.